# Username in WebTokenRequestResult is empty

Tags: windows-store-apps, microsoft-account

in a Windows 10 UWP I try use WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync to get the result from a login with a Microsoft account.
I get a WebTokenRequestResult with Success. ResponseData[0] contains a WebAccount with an ID - but the UserName is empty.
The scope of the call is wl.basic - so I should get a lot of information...
I'm not sure how to retrieve extra information - and for the current test the Username would be OK.

I checked out the universal samples - and there I found a snippet which tries to do what I'm trying - an output of webTokenRequestResult.ResponseData[0].WebAccount.UserName.

By the way - the example output is also empty.

Is this a bug - or what do I (and the MS in the samples) have to do to get the users profile data (or at least the Username)?

Comment: I second this. Why is it that the UserName field is empty? I just wanted to implement something similar to google play games or apples game center where i can get a basic username and id back from the device for use in the game project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager), you have to make a specific REST API call to retrieve it:

```
var restApi = new Uri(@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=" +     result.ResponseData[0].Token);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var infoResult = await client.GetAsync(restApi);
    string content = await infoResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(content);
    string id = jsonObject["id"].GetString();
    string name = jsonObject["name"].GetString();
}
```

As to why the WebAccount property doesn't get set... *shrugs*

And FYI, the "id" returned here is entirely different from the WebAccount.Id property returned with the authentication request.